# Refresh GridView on click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Currently I'm working on a webform app and I populate the `DevExpress` grid on selected value from a `ASPxComboBox`. I have this part working no problem. However my requirement is to refresh the grid if there is any new data added into the database so the users can see this. So I've added a button and on the click event I try to refresh the data but the grid doesn't refresh. If I step through the code I can see that the new values from the database are there in my `DataTable`. I can't seem to figure out what could be causing the grid to not refresh. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is what I have so far

**SelectedIndexChangedEvent**

```
protected void TrainingOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ASPxComboBox ddl = (ASPxComboBox)sender;
   string[] parameters = { ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() };
   TrainingGrid.DataSource = dto.PopulateTrainingData(parameters);
   TrainingGrid.DataBind();
}
```

**ButtonClickEvent**

```
protected void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] parameters = { TrainingOptions.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() };
   TrainingGrid.DataSource = dto.PopulateTrainingData(parameters);
   TrainingGrid.DataBind();
 }
```

**PopulateTrainingDara**

```
public DataTable PopulateTrainingData(params string[] parameters)
{
   //Loop through DataTable Here
   ...

   HttpContext.Current.Session["GridDT"] = mainTable;
   return mainTable;
}
```

**DataBinding**

```
protected void TrainingGrid_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TrainingGrid.DataSource = Session["GridDT"];
}
```

**Page_LoadEvent**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dropDownOptions = dto.GetTrainingData("MyQuery");

    //Add datasource to TrainingOptions dropdown
    TrainingOptions.DataSource = dropDownOptions;
    TrainingOptions.Text = "Please choose";
    TrainingOptions.TextField = "ID";
    TrainingOptions.DataBindItems();
}
```

**Markup**

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="TrainingOptions" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TrainingOptions_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="combo-box"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="TrainingGrid" runat="server" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="TrainingGrid_HtmlDataCellPrepared" OnDataBinding="TrainingGrid_DataBinding"></dx:ASPxGridView>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="Refresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="Refresh_Click" AutoPostBack="false"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

**Note:** I am not populating the grid in the `Page_Load` event.

If any other information is required please let me know.

Comment: I see that the AutoPostBack option of the ASPxButton to set to False. In this case, the button won't send requests to the server to process its click. The client-side CheckedChanged event will be raised. Set the property to True. Does this fix the issue?

Comment: why are you using the ondatabinding event again??? just binding it to datasource should do the trick. try removing the OnDataBinding event and see

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I tried your suggestion, however i still have the same issue

Comment: It looks strange. Try to do this in the following way. Set AutoPostBack to False and handle the ASPxClientButton.CheckedChanged client-side event. In the event handler, perform a callback on the Grid using the ASPxClientGridView.PerformCallback method. This will force the ASPxGridView.CustomCallback on the server. In the event handler, call DataBind for the Grid. Let me know your results.

Comment: Gosha - You might be missing something here - when he clicks the button it IS posting back, its not an auto post back because it is being triggered by a user clicking the button so what you are suggesting is not the cause. Mysterio has a point, I dont see why you are setting the datasource in the databinding event - BUT that would not cause the problem you are seeing. can you edit and include your page load method (I know you are not populating the grid in there but what about the drop down list that you get the training options from?)

Comment: Where are you populating the training options drop down?

Comment: @D3vy Sorry my bad I just realised I am populating that in the page_load event, i'll update the question

Comment: If that is populated and you are not checking for !isPostBack then the drop down will be reset to its default value before the data is retrieved to be bound to the grid.

Comment: @D3vy Updated my code and I am checking for `!IsPostBack`

Comment: Are you using update panels on this page?

Comment: @D3vy No panel being used on the page

Comment: Okay, just to go over the issue : If you put a break point in the button click event its being hit? And you can see the drop down selected value is correct? when you step in to the dto.get... method you can see the new values? Its just not displaying the new values in the grid?

Comment: @D3vy You've got that spot on.. It's confusing me so much I can't figure out why it's doing this.. the break point is being hit, new data is there, selected value is also correct but it just doesn't want to display

Comment: Ive mocked the whole thing up in VS and it works for me... http://3pchallenge.co.uk/gridexample.zip Ive botched the data layer and its using lists instead of tables but the bulk of it is the same as yours and it seems to be ok, Its not something as simple as caching on the client side is it?

Comment: @D3vy Thanks for the effort but I'm using `DevExpress` `ASPxGridView` not the normal `GridView`

Comment: I know, that was the only thing that stood out as being a likley cause - it would be worth switching it out for a standard grid view to see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105269/discussion-between-izzy-and-d3vy).

Comment: Can you post full code of Page_LoadEvent?

Comment: @Lesmian The code I posted in the question body is all I have in the `Page_LoadEvent`

Comment: @Izzy May I ask why you are storing datatable to session? Is it used in another part of the system too?

Comment: @Lesmian Yes, you're correct it used on another part of the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've recreated your example with the latest trial version of DevExpress Suite. I removed unnecessary code and this is the code that works in my case:

```
public partial class DevExpress : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dropDownOptions = new DataTable();
            dropDownOptions.Columns.Add("id");
            DataRow row = dropDownOptions.NewRow();
            row["id"] = 1;
            dropDownOptions.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dropDownOptions.NewRow();
            row["id"] = 2;
            dropDownOptions.Rows.Add(row);
            dropDownOptions.AcceptChanges();

            TrainingOptions.DataSource = dropDownOptions;
            TrainingOptions.Text = "Please choose";
            TrainingOptions.TextField = "ID";
            TrainingOptions.DataBindItems();
        }
    }

    protected void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] parameters = { TrainingOptions.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() };
        TrainingGrid.DataSource = PopulateTrainingData(parameters);
        TrainingGrid.DataBind();
    }

    protected void TrainingOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxComboBox ddl = (ASPxComboBox)sender;
        string[] parameters = { ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() };
        TrainingGrid.DataSource = PopulateTrainingData(parameters);
        TrainingGrid.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable PopulateTrainingData(params string[] parameters)
    {
        DataTable mainTable = (DataTable)Session["GridDT"] ?? new DataTable();
        if (!mainTable.Columns.Contains("id"))
        {
            mainTable.Columns.Add("id");
        }

        DataRow row = mainTable.NewRow();
        row["id"] = parameters[0];
        mainTable.Rows.Add(row);
        mainTable.AcceptChanges();

        HttpContext.Current.Session["GridDT"] = mainTable;
        return mainTable;
    }
}
```

And the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DevExpress.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.DevExpress" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="TrainingOptions" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TrainingOptions_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="combo-box"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="TrainingGrid" runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridView>
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="Refresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="Refresh_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>
</asp:Content>
```

If this is not working for you you should check which version of DevExpress controls are you using and maybe update them if its possible. Or maybe you are doing something more which you didn't post here.